# How to use MapStruct for different data types?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

I have two types of data that I want to map:

**SignUpUserDto:**

```
public class SignUpUserDto {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String title;
}
```

**SignUpUser:**

```
@Entity
public class SignUpUser {
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private Title title;
}
```

**Title:**

```
public enum Title {
    JUNIOR("junior"),
    MIDDLE("middle"),
    SENIOR("senior"),
    MANAGER("manager");

    private final String title;

    Title(final String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.title;
    }
}
```

- For **DTO** title member is a **String**.
- For **entity** title member is a **Title**.

How should the mapper looks like?

Should I pass title already converted in **Service**?

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface SignUpUserMapper {
    SignUpUserMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(SignUpUserMapper.class);
    @Mapping(target = "title", expression = "title")
    public SignUpUserDto signUpUserToSignUpUserDto(SignUpUser signUpUser, String title);
    @Mapping(target = "title", source = "title")
    public SignUpUser signUpUserDtoToSignUpUser(SignUpUserDto signUpUserDto, Title title);
}
```

Or should I do conversion in **Mapper**?

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring",  imports = Title.class)
public interface SignUpUserMapper {
    SignUpUserMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(SignUpUserMapper.class);
    @Mapping(target = "title", expression = "java(signUpUser.getTitle().toString())")
    public SignUpUserDto signUpUserToSignUpUserDto(SignUpUser signUpUser);
    @Mapping(target = "title", source = "java(new Title(signUpUserDto.getTitle()))")
    public SignUpUser signUpUserDtoToSignUpUser(SignUpUserDto signUpUserDto);
}
```

Comment: You can't do `new Title(...)` since Title is Enum class

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Should I pass title already converted in Service?

You definitely shoul NOT do it. It is converter's job, not service's

Try following approach:

1) Add conversion method to enum class

```
enum Title {
    ...

    public static Title fromString(String title) {
        if (title != null) {
            for (Title t : Title.values()) {
                if (t.toString().equals(title)) {
                    return t;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

2) Add 2 conversion methods to Mapper interface (Java 8+ only)

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface SignUpUserMapper {
    SignUpUserDto signUpUserToSignUpUserDto(SignUpUser signUpUser);
    SignUpUser signUpUserDtoToSignUpUser(SignUpUserDto signUpUserDto);

    default String fromEnum(Title title) {
        return title == null ? null : title.toString();
    }

    default Title toEnum(String title) {
        return title == null ? null : Title.fromString(title);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've seen in documentation one more option with an abstract class instead of interface. What is the difference between this two approaches? Can you give me some use cases? Thank you!

Comment: You should use abstract class instead of interface when you need to autowire some bean(s) into mapper

Comment: What is the approach for Java 8- ? Why is not a good approach using imports and @Mapping annotations? Should I include repositories in Mappers with autowire and retrieve data there or should I do this in Service?

Comment: Same approach for Java 8-, but since there are no default interface methods in Java 8-, you will use abstract classes instead

Comment: One addition: I think conversion to string is done automatically by mapstruct, hence you should not have to add a method for that. The conversion from string could be done by a backing map wich is probably more efficient.

Comment: @Sjaak I believe this approach with an explicit `fromString()` method is useful for different types of data, for example `Integer` with method `fromInteger()`

Comment: @robert I don't question the need for a fromString itself but merely the implementation.. that could be done IMHO a look in a static initialized map rather than in a loop.

Answer (score 3):

Use the second option like this:

```
 @Mapper(componentModel = "spring",  imports = Title.class)                     
public interface SignUpUserMapper {
SignUpUserMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(SignUpUserMapper.class);
@Mapping(target = "title", expression = "java(signUpUser.getTitle().toString())")
public SignUpUserDto signUpUserToSignUpUserDto(SignUpUser signUpUser);
@Mapping(target = "title", source = "java(Title.valueOf(signUpUserDto.getTitle().toUpperCase()))")
public SignUpUser signUpUserDtoToSignUpUser(SignUpUserDto signUpUserDto);            
}
```